# What is the jQuery/Greasemonkey of Server Fault? And what will it be for Super User?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, superuser, serverfault, memes

As a long-time user of Stack Overflow, I have noticed that a certain answer seems to be the 'catch-all' answer for that website: **jQuery**. It seems that if you have any type of question related to a website at all, *someone* will post an answer using jQuery, regardless of its helpfulness. It has even become its own meme in some circles:

> I see you are trying to [insert task here]. You should totally drop that and try **jQuery**
>
> [Insert optional jQuery example here].

I have also noticed in recent times that Greasemonkey scripts are becoming the new jQuery for Meta Stack Exchange, thanks in large part to Greasemonkey-scripter extraordinaire [Jonathan Sampson](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/130154/jonathan-sampson). Oftentimes now I will watch posts on Meta wondering when someone will come in with a Greasemonkey script to add or modify some piece of functionality that was requested.

What I am wondering now is: as a user who does not patrol Server Fault with any type of regularity, does a similar meme exist there as well? Is there a "catch-all" answer that seems to show up no matter what the question is?

Also, what do you predict will be the "catch-all" answer for Super User?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I can only guess that Super User's catch-all will be

> Have you tried turning it off and on
>   again?

Or as Moss from The IT Crowd refers to it:

> Have you tried forcing an unexpected reboot?

Comment: yeah, 3 times just like they always tell me to.

Comment: Just use the term "power-cycle" and you'll totally sound official.

Comment: Make sure that you unplug it and wait 30 min too.  Other wise the reset won't 'take.'

Answer (score 12):

Another one for Super User, inspired by the jQuery meme:

> "I see you are trying to use Windows. You should totally drop that and try Ubuntu."

Answer (score 5):

Another catch-all answer that appears often on SO (and will probably appear more often on SU) is the obligatory [xkcd](http://xkcd.com/) comic.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't been to SF in a while, but if it isn't "Have you tried rebooting?", then those guys are all hacks.

Answer (score 2):

"Have you tried rebooting into safe mode?"

Answer (score 2):

`chkdsk /r` and grab a coffee.